# Embedding TinyMCE Control Inside jQuery FormBuilder Paragraph Content

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc, tinymce, formbuilder

I have an ASP.NET MVC 7 website where I'm using both jQuery FormBuilder (https://formbuilder.online/) and TinyMCE 6.  What I'd like to do if possible is to change the Paragraph Content section so that it's always a TinyMCE WYSIWYG. Here's where I've done so far:

```
//add event listener to handle TinyMCE FormBuilder paragraphs:
        const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
                if (mutation.addedNodes.length) {
                    $(mutation.addedNodes).find('textarea').each(function () {
                        tinymce.init({
                            selector: '#' + this.id,
                            setup: function (editor) {
                                editor.on('Remove', function (e) {
                                    observer.observe($('.build-wrap')[0], {
                                        childList: true,
                                        subtree: true
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                        });
                        observer.disconnect(); // disconnect the observer after initializing TinyMCE
                    });
                }
            });
        });

        observer.observe($('.build-wrap')[0], {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
        });
```

The problem is that this converts any Text Area field into a WYSIWYG (which isn't what I'm chasing) and doesn't convert the Text Area I do want converted.  Any thoughts?

[image]